# Showing changes to RC files with BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket

Why is it that when I try to view a commit that has changes to a RC file it says:

[image: Bitbucket - RC files]

I can use TortoiseGit on my PC with the same commit and view it as a text file, which is what I expected. But not online with BitBucket.

Comment: Any comments on this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is the file encoding: UCS-2 LE BOM (a Microsoft version of UTF-16).

There is currently no fix, as even `git diff` only supports UTF-8. (Tortoise uses an own diff tool.) The workaround is to change file encoding before commit / after checkout, but I don't think that is  suitable on the long run. In the meantime, one can only hope that Atlassian will provide UCS-2 support for Bitbucket Server.